# Random number in C# is not uniformly distributed

Tags: c#, random

I am learning C# to implement Genetic Algorithm. From several execution, I found that the random number did not produce good result, that is the random number is not uniformly distributed.

Here is my code:

```
class Individual
{
    private int[,] myInd;

    public Individual()
    {
        //
    }

    public Individual(int numberOfChromosomes, int numberOfJobs, int numberOfMachines)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.myInd = new int[numberOfChromosomes, numberOfJobs];
        int machineid;
        int something;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChromosomes; i++)
        {
            int[] dummy = new int[numberOfJobs];
            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfJobs; j++)
                {
                    dummy[j] = j;
                }
                dummy = Shuffle<int>(dummy);
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfChromosomes; j++)
                {
                    //Random rand = new Random();
                    machineid = rand.Next(numberOfMachines);
                    dummy[j] = machineid;
                }
                dummy = Shuffle<int>(dummy);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfChromosomes; j++)
                {
                    something = rand.Next(10);
                    dummy[j] = something;
                }
                dummy = Shuffle<int>(dummy);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfJobs; j++)
            {
                this.myInd[i, j] = dummy[j];
            }
            dummy = null;
        }
    }//End for Constructor

    public void Show()
    {
        int numberOfChromosomes = this.GetMyInd().GetUpperBound(0);
        int numberOfJobs = this.GetMyInd().GetUpperBound(1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfChromosomes; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= numberOfJobs; j++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(this.GetMyInd()[i, j]);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        var random = rand;
        for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            // Pick random element to swap.
            int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
            // Swap.
            T tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i - 1];
            array[i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public int[,] GetMyInd()
    {
        return this.myInd;
    }

}//End for Individual Class
```

That zero value occurs more than any other value in one execution. Here is for example.

```
9360471582
0000002002
0002009009
```

The second and the third chromosome have a problem with random number. Can you show whats wrong with my code? Thanks.
Best regards, 
Bobby

Comment: Are you calling `new Random` multiple times in the same millisecond? Best practice is to say `private static Random rand = new Random();` in your class and then use the same `rand` throughout, rather than making a new one.

Comment: Anyone that's ever watched a Roulette table knows that random numbers are seldom even distributed.  If they're evenly distributed, they're not random, they're predictable.  I suggest you try over on codereview.stackexchange.com where code reviews are supposed to be done.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "evenly distributed." If every number but one has been selected, that doesn't make that number more likely to come up next. But if you spin the wheel 10,000 times you won't see one number come up 20% of the time and it's most likely that every number will have been selected.

Comment: Thank you @EricLippert to show me to use static method. I will try to research it.

Comment: This question gets asked at least once a week, please try to search before asking trivial questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Random` numbers are distributed pretty evenly.

`.Next(i)` will always return a value less than `i`. `.Next(1)` will always return zero.

You're iterating over a range of numbers from the 2 to the length of the array (in reverse order, doesn't matter) and calling `.Next(i)` for each number. Zero is the only number that's a guaranteed possibility each time. By the time `i` equals 2 the odds of zero are 50%. So it's likely to show up more.

Comment: Thanks to point out my error. In second and third chromosome, the numberOfChromosome must be replaced by numberOfJobs. Thanks @Scott Hannen

Comment: Just to add my little brick. Here is the implementation of the Random class 
[Random.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Random.cs)